# How can i free memory in C++/C? When would i write free(a);? Function is returing pointer

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

Code:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class KMP { 
    public:     
        int * prefix_array(string);
        bool kmp_search(string,string,int *);       
};

int * KMP::prefix_array(string pattern) {
    int m,q,k;
    int *a;
    string p;
    p=pattern;
    m = p.length();
    a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);    
    a[0] = -1;
    k=-1;
    for(q=1;q<m;q++) {
        while(k>-1 && p[k+1] != p[q]) {
            k=a[k];
        }
        if(p[k+1]==p[q]) {
            k=k+1;
        }
        a[q]=k;
    }
    /*
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++) {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }   
    printf("\n");
    */
    return a;
}

bool KMP::kmp_search(string str, string pattern,int *a) {
    int n,m,q,i;
    string S,p;
    S = str;
    p = pattern;

    n = str.length();
    m = pattern.length();
    q = -1;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        while(q>-1 && p[q+1] != S[i]) {
            q=a[q];
        }
        if(p[q+1] == S[i]) {
            q=q+1;
        }
        if(q==m-1) {
            q=a[q];         
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    //freopen("in.txt","r",stdin);

    int testCase,num;
    char ch;
    string str,pattern;
    char str2[250];
    bool check;
    int *arr;

    KMP *obj = new KMP();
    scanf("%d\n",&testCase);    

    while(testCase--) {
        getline(cin,str);
        //cout<<str<<endl;
        scanf("%d\n",&num);
        //printf("%d\n",num);
        while(num--) {
            getline(cin,pattern);                       
            arr=obj->prefix_array(pattern);             
            check = obj->kmp_search(str,pattern,arr);
            if(check) {
                printf("y\n");
            } else {
                printf("n\n");
            }           
        }
    }
    delete obj;
    return 0;
}
```

in.txt (input):

```
2
abcdefghABCDEFGH
3
ababaca
abc
abAB
xyz
1
xyz
```

I'm trying to free memory in `int * KMP::prefix_array(string pattern) {` .
It's allocating memory with this: `a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);` , this function returns the pointer. So how can i free that memory?

Any answer will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I free memory in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069205/how-do-i-free-memory-in-c)

Comment: Call `free` on the pointer when you are done with the memory. Even better use `vector<int>`.

Comment: This is **not** C. Don't tag indiscriminately, and don't mention irrelevancies in your title. As it is C++, you should use `new` and `delete`, not `malloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: 2.5K rep and you don't know how to ask a question? How does that happen?

Comment: @jxh, I know `free(a);` frees memory, but when would i write this? It's returning that pointer.

Comment: @EJP, If i use new, then when would i write delete? It's returning that pointer.

Comment: @EJP, malloc and free c are statements, that's why i added c tag.

Comment: @MorrisonChang, the answer is not in that link.

Comment: You would write `free(a)` when you are done with `a`.

Comment: Upon review I agree that the original dup suggest wasn't the right answer. However I agree with @jxh to just free the alloc when you are done with it. Your class as written exposes the int array directly and doesn't try to encapsulate it anyway or wrap in it some lifecycle.

Comment: @shibly They are *not* statements. They are functions in the standard C and C++ libraries. Your code is C++ and that is therefore what your question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function that returns an allocated pointer means that ownership of that memory is being transferred to the caller of that function. It is up to the code that receives the returned pointer to deallocate the memory.

While using `malloc()` and `free()` in C++ is not entirely without precedent, it should generally be avoided. You could avoid the problem entirely by changing your code to use `std::vector<int>` instead of an `int *`.

Comment: If i do `delete[] arr;` at the end in main function, will it deallocate array "`a`" created in `prefix_array` function (`a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);`)?

Comment: @What would happen if i use `free(arr);` at the end in main function ?

Comment: What would happen if you call `arr = new int[5]; arr = new int[100]; delete[] arr;`?

Comment: It will deallocate arr. My question is if i use `free(arr);` will it deallocate array "a" in prefix_array function?

Comment: Are you sure it will deallocate `arr`? How many allocations have been assigned to `arr`? How many deallocations should be done to release all the allocated memory?

Comment: I didn't do: `arr=new int[5];` i did: `arr=obj->prefix_array(pattern);` , then if i do `free(arr);` will it free "a" , `a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);` is in prefix_array function?

Comment: If `malloc()` returns the pointer value `0xabcdabcd`, then the code `free(0xabcdabcd)` will free the memory.