# How can I free allocated Memory?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

i have a homework and i have some problems

```
buch->title = malloc(MAX_STR* sizeof(char));
buch->author = malloc(MAX_STR* sizeof(char));
```

how can i free this allocated memory?

Comment: `free(buch->title);`

Comment: `free(buch->author);`

Comment: This is not homework doing site. If this is your homework, then for sure, there is written somewhere in your materials how to free memory. Deal with your own homework on your own

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I free memory in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069205/how-do-i-free-memory-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Frees all memory:

```
system("reboot");
```

Answer (score 0):

With free

```
free(buch->title)
free(buch->author)
```

btw, later you should free buch too.

```
free(buch)
```

pd: Here is explained with 1-2D, if you need it later. [How do I free memory in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069205/how-do-i-free-memory-in-c)