# std::vector not free'ing memory

Tags: c++, stdvector, allocator

Under a specific access pattern, I have found a vector of vectors (`std::vector<std::vector<Datum>>`) might not free all its allocated memory when it is destructed.

For example, in the following code:

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <vector>

struct Datum { char payload[128]; };

int main() {
    std::mt19937 gen(1234);
    std::normal_distribution rand(0., N / 10.);

    // Resident memory ~ 150 kB

    {
        std::vector<std::vector<Datum>> vv(N);

        for (int i {}; i < 10000000; ++i) {
            const auto n = static_cast<int>(std::abs(rand(gen))) % N;
            vv[n].push_back(Datum());
        }

        // Resident memory ~ 1.2 GB
    }

    // vv is destructed, but resident memory ~ 40 MB
}
```

By the time `vv` is destructed, there is still some memory that was allocated to `vv` that isn't freed.

(This is a minimum working example. The real code involves partitioning radio astronomy data that ends up with a handful of highly populated partitions and a long tail - *and neither the number of partitions or their occupancy can be predicted ahead of time.* I have approximated the real world code with a normal distribution here; in practice the actual code often ends up with a much higher proportion of the memory retained and eventually dies with an OOM error.)

I'm assuming this is caused by memory fragmentation within the C++ allocator (?) but I don't understand why exactly. I would also like to understand how to mitigate this problem.

**Edit:** some additional notes

- This was compiled using GCC 12.3.0
- I can resolve the situation if I call `v.reserve(?)` on each vector in `vv` with a sufficiently large allocation reinforcing my belief this is a memory fragmentation issue

Comment: Which version of which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Fooble gcc 12.3.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.6

Comment: Note 1: Memory freed is not necessarily memory returned to the operation system. It can be retained internally for future use. Note 2: You report that before allocating vv you were using 150 MB; after fully populating vv 1.2 GB; after releasing vv 40 MB. Those numbers are curious and, on the surface at least, contradict your conclusion. Note 3: Trying to get correct numbers for currently allocated memory can be tricky and require accessing implementation internals. Unless you drill down to this level, you are likely to get wrong answers.

Comment: @AviBerger Re: note2 that was a typo - it was 150 kB (not MB) at the start. Regarding keeping it for future use: in the real program it holds onto GB other otherwise freed memory causing the program to eventually OOM.

Comment: 1) Does your posted code OOM? 2) (Especially if it doesn't) Have you run your original code with valgrind and then with address sanitizer to check for other things before going down this path? 3) [This](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)  looks interesting, but I don't know if it would be useful to you.

Comment: @AviBerger Yes, it eventually OOMs. As I said it holds onto GBs of otherwise free memory that accrues each time I partition the data.

Comment: There are also alternative memory managers like jemalloc and mimalloc, that are specifically fragmentation-resistant. You are mostly testing the default memory allocator implementation here.

Comment: Once `vv` is destructed, the memory is freed at the C++ level (through `operator delete` with a standard allocator, which typically calls `free` internally). However, the question is whether this memory is then released from the process to the os. Typically, it is not. And, there is nothing you can do about is by C/C++ mechanisms themselves. See, e.g., this explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9069474/580083.

Comment: Eventually?  Posted code does a single run with a fixed seed to the prng.  Repeated runs should be identical. "Eventually" suggests to me a mismatch between the post and what you are doing in your tests. The holding on to freed memory in the process that you have been focused on is 99.99% normal behavior and a red herring as per the close duplicates. OTOH, heap fragmentation could be your OOM issue and is a real potential., but it could also simply be allocating more memory than you realize. Your reserve experiment could be consistent with either.

Comment: Do you know how much memory you can dynamically allocate on your setup? (Beware of overcommit.) Have you estimated how much memory you might need, taking into account how std::vector reallocates? My quick, faulty, and certainly wrong estimate says I'd want 3.2 GB available for the posted code varied to allow different sequences & distributions (with no allowance for fragmentation included).